# How to parse string to list without eval or ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Is there any way to convert a list containing unicode strings to a proper `list` without using `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()` in Python?

For example:

```
"[u'hello', u'hi']"
```

to

```
['hello', 'hi']
```

Comment: You can write your own parser for it. This is simpler if you have a guarantee about the structure of the list, but there's no convincing reason not to use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Could you add more context into why `eval()` and `literal_eval()` are not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for?

```
a = "[u'hello', u'hi']".translate(None, "[]u'' ")
a = a.split(',')
print(a) #['hello', 'hi']
```

Seems to fail when you have `'u'` in string so you can go with:

```
a = "[u'hello', u'hi', u'uyou']".translate(None, "[]' ")
a = [item[1:] for item in a.split(',')]
```

Comment: Could of issues with this - the OP has this tagged Python 3.x, which means the `str.translate` example provided won't work and if there happens to be a `[` or `]` (or spaces etc...) in the strings themselves you'll lose them...

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the formatting of your input:

- it only contains "strings"
- if there are always `u` in front of the strings,
- each string is inside single quotations `'`
- there is always no whitespace before the `,` but one after.
- there are no whitespaces before or after the `[` and `]`

you could simply strip the left `[u'` and the right `']` (for convenience I just slice it from the fourth element to the second to last element), then split at `', u'` and you're done:

```
>>> s = "[u'hello', u'hi']"
>>> s[3:-2].split("', u'")
['hello', 'hi']
```